# How do I split a stack of items?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I have a stack of medpacs, and I'd like to trade a handful of them to another group member, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to split the stack.

How do I split a stack of items?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shift and left click the item stack to bring up this dialog:

[image]

If you've started typing into chat then this will leave the item linked in your chat window, *in addition* to splitting the stack, because the UI is terrible that way.

To avoid the chat linking you can Shift and right click the item instead, *and then drag the mouse off of the item* before releasing the mouse button.  That last quirk is somewhat mind boggling, and makes it easy to miss.

Comment: wow, it works but it is astonishingly unintuitive...the icon doesn't even drag as you move your mouse

Comment: Well they are getting bombarder with metric s***tonnes of feedback in the forums, and a lot of it seems to be getting noticed by strangely eloquent people who use golden writing, so hopefully, with time, it will all change for the better :)